# Calculation of degrees of freedom for chi-square test

Tags: chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom, genetics

I am not sure how to calculate the df for the following data:

[image]

The data is for a cross between flies to see if the observed phenotypic ratios are following the predictions of Mendel's laws. The total number of fly progeny was 233 and the data has two categories: wild type flies and vestigial winged flies.

To calculate the expected ratio I used the total number of fly progeny from the table. I used the following formula to get the df:

df = (Number of categories) -1 - (Number of parameters estimated from the data)

Therefore, the df should be df = 2 -1 -1 = 0.

But this is obviously incorrect as for the chi-square test the df cannot be zero. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You didn't estimate any parameters: you used the *theoretically stipulated* value of $3/4$ for the proportion of the wild type.  There is $2-1-0=1$ degree of freedome.

Answer (score -1):

DF = (c1 - 1) * (c2 -1), where ci is the number of categories on a given dimension. Here c1 = c2 = 2, and DF = 1.

Comment: Where do you see a $2\times 2$ table??  The one shown in the question is $2\times 1.$

Comment: I am sorry but I can not understand what you mean?